# Playwright: Finding Child Elements Inside Parent Locator

Tags: playwright

I would find 'div.vc_col-sm-4 h4' if only they are inside 'div.vc_col-sm-4 div.wpb_wrapper' using the locator:

```
const title = page.locator('div.vc_col-sm-4 div.wpb_wrapper').locator('div.vc_col-sm-4 h4')
```

It always failed to find the title elements because the selectors were overlapping. I can find them directly from the page, but I can't make sure if they are inside the parent container.

```
const title = page.locator('div.vc_col-sm-4 h4')
```

or using only 'h4' in the 2nd locator:

```
const title = page.locator('div.vc_col-sm-4 div.wpb_wrapper').locator('h4')
```

However, I don't want to change the title selectors. How do we solve this problem without changing the selectors?

Element tree:
[image]

Comment: Can you show an example of the HTML? I'm not really clear what you're asking. [CSS selectors are discouraged](https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#locate-by-css-or-xpath), so there [may be a fundamentally better way to achieve whatever you're really trying to achieve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use an internal filter/parent locators https://playwright.dev/docs/other-locators#parent-element-locator

```js
page.locator(".wpb_wrapper", { has: page.locator(".vc_col-sm-4 h4") }).locator("h4");
```

But yes, common practice is not to do such complex things with CSS as it's gonna be hard to support in the future